# Skinning WinAPI Controls

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, skinning

If you've ever seen an application in the Adobe Creative Suite 5 (CS5), you may have noticed that it doesn't look like the native Windows GUI.. They have modified it to have a different look to it.

Where would someone begin to make an application that has a custom skin? CS5 uses the Adobe Source library for it's widget/control management, so I tried downloading and compiling the Adobe Source Library to see if I could make a nice skinned app like Photoshop CS5, but after finally getting it to compile and tested it, I realized the library was only for managing widgets and not skinning the GUI, like CS5 has.

Where would I begin to make a nice skinned program like Adobe Cs5 applications? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Do I simply use the WM_PAINT Message from WinAPI and render my own widgets using openGL or something?

Comment: Lots of the programs in the Adobe Creative Suite use custom control libraries, rather than the standard controls provided by the Windows API. It's not a simple matter to skin the existing controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use QT and QML. It doesn't have a steep learning curve. You define your GUI with JavaScript and add lots of effects and enjoy using PNGs in every single thing you can imagine. Then you do your application logic with C++. In fact you can do some fairly advanced things other than UI with QML but it's better to seperate concerns as always.

I use it at work for a product to be released. Overriding WM_PAINT is not the only way in Windows but I strongly recommend QT instead of Win32 API when it comes to custom drawn UI. At least to my experience, it is way easier than my adventures with Win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement custom controls by yourself, you need to implement own WM_PAINT and draw with using GDI/GDI+. For toplevel windows and popups you can use [Layered windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#layered). But I think you can find a lot of professional custom controls over internet for reasonable price if you don't want to implement by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think your choices re creating a modern skinned app are: [QT](http://qt.nokia.com/) or [WPF](http://windowsclient.net/default.aspx) (via C++/CLI).

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing Win32 API application and you do not want to rewrite it using a library that supports skinning you might want to have a look at [Stardock DirectSkin](http://www.stardock.com/products/directskin/).

If you decide to rewrite your application I would also recommend Qt. [Guitar Pro 6](http://www.guitar-pro.com/en/index.php) was rewritten using Qt, read more about their experience [here](http://blog.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/how-qt-can-turn-you-into-a-guitar-maestro/).

Comment: Updated link for the Guitar Pro 6 blog post: http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/how-qt-can-turn-you-into-a-guitar-maestro/